# Center my navigation bar with CSS

Tags: css

Since a couple of days I'm working on a navigation bar for my website. But I want to center it . Here's my CSS

```
.nav{
    float:right;width:980px
}
.nav ul {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.nav li {
    float: right;
    width: 87px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition: border .5s;
    -moz-transition: border .5s;
    -o-transition: border .5s;
    -ms-transition: border .5s;
    transition: border .5s;
}
.nav a {
    display: block;
    width:87px;height: 74px;
}
.no-touch .nav a:hover ,
.nav a:active ,
.nav a:focus {
    height: 84px;
}   
.nav li span {
    display: block;
    font-family:"Droid Arabic Kufi";
```

Comment: Could you add some HTML as well and throw it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: set the navbars display to block..

Answer (score 0):

The float on the nav is unnecessary and the with on the `.nav` prevents the `.nav ul` to center.

```
.nav {
   float: right; // Remove this.
   width: 100%; // Change this.
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7TBHn/2/

Though in my jsfiddle I use the nav element to be more semantic, but other then that it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.nav ul`:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

This should center it. Hope this helps!